# Found a conflicting setters with name setWallpaper (conflicts with setWallpaper defined on android.content.ContextWrapper)

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to save `HashMap` object in Firebase database with the code below.

**Java Code**

```
public static void notifyAllMembers(final Context context, final String uploader, final Uri uri, final DatabaseReference path, final String name, final boolean forWho) {

    new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("notification")
                    .child("members");

            final HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap();
            map.put("userID", uploader);
            map.put("uri", uri);
            map.put("livePath", path);
            map.put("fileName", name);
            map.put("forAdmins", forWho);

            reference.push().setValue(map).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Notified !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

        }
    });
}
```

This **runtime exception** is thrown:

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Found a conflicting setters with name: setWallpaper (conflicts with setWallpaper defined on android.content.ContextWrapper)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.<init>(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:504)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.loadOrCreateBeanMapperForClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:312)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:166)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$200(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:47)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:658)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:167)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$200(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:47)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:658)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:167)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$200(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:47)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:658)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:167)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$200(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:47)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:658)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:167)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:141)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertToPlainJavaTypes(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:60)
    at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.setValueInternal(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:292)
    at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.setValue(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:166)
    at com.codestream.league.Connection.Notifications$1.run(Notifications.java:35)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6946)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

Comment: can you show me your model class?

Comment: Please show us the content of your `POJO` class. Please also responde with @AlexMamo